# Trying to access codespace, but unable to write or make program changes

Tags: c, github

Trying to access a virtual codespace via GitHub, and I keep getting the same error.
I was in the same codespace a day yesterday, but from another computer.

I keep getting the same error:

/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start': (.text+0x1b): undefined reference to` main'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [: mario] Error 1

Any idea whats wrong?
I am very new to programming and I have no clue what is going wrong.
Thankful for any input : )

Comment: It looks like you are trying to link your compiled file(s) but there's no `main` function in any of the filles you're trying to link together.

Comment: Does that mean I have deleted my main function or if not how do I link to it? 
There is basically nothing im the program yet, but I cannot compile my mario.c file

Comment: Is `mario.c` empty? Is that the only `.c` file in your project?

Comment: I have more files, but not in the folder I am in. I get the same code wether I empty it completely or of it has some bit of code. 
I am following the program cs50, and this is the second weeks program, using a virtual platform of vscode

Comment: Well, all programs need a starting point and that's `main`. Put `#include <stdio.h>`  _newline_   `int main(void) { puts("Hello world"); }` in a `.c` file and then compile it and you should get a program that you can run.

Comment: I have done that too, and I still get the same error. 
I get the error seemingly no matter what I put in the file.

Comment: Then you either haven't saved the file or you are not actually compiling that file but something else. Try this command: `echo 'int main(void) {}' > foo.c ; gcc -o foo foo.c && ./foo` - Do you get any errors?

Comment: I tried it now from a different computer again, and it worked directly. I took a schreenshot, but maybe it would be more valuable with a screenshot of the time when it doesnt work?

Comment: Screenshots are rarely wanted here. Instead copy the full error message as text and include it in the question together with a [mre].

Comment: Ah Yeah I understand. 
Well I have now tried it again on the computer I used when I got the error, and I cant seem to get the error anymore. 
Could it have been an issue with loading the codespace itself?

Comment: Possibly. I don't know anything about said codespace.

Comment: Completely understandable. Anyways, the problem seems to have resolved itself, but I greatly appreciate your help! Thank you